# Объект принимает значение null после инициализации

Tags: java

Такая ситуация:

```
public void addLoadedWorld(DayWorld<Order> world){
    WorldTreeNode wtn = new WorldTreeNode(world, new ArrayList());
    addLoadedWorldTreeNode(wtn); //Здесь дебаггер сообщает, что wtn = null
}
```

Конструктор класса WorldTreeNode:

```
public WorldTreeNode(DayWorld<Order> world, List children){
    this.world = world;
    this.children = children;
}
```

Почему подобное может происходить?

Comment: _Почему подобное может происходить?_ - например вы смотрите значение переменной до того как его присвоили

Comment: Вызов метода внутри wtn приводит к NullPointerException, деббагер утверждает, что wtn = null.

Comment: @СоловьевТимур - Всем понятно, что в показанном коде это не может происходить. Нам остается только гадать - что непродуктивно. Покажите код метода `addLoadedWorldTreeNode` с указанием строки, где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Невозможно чтобы new возвращал null, если виртуальная машина работает корректно.

Comment: Добавьте код класса WorldTreeNode и класса где вызывается метод addLoadedWorld(). Также покажите нам какую ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: можете добавить в вопрос StackTrace?